# Unable to raise zticklabel in 3D plot when using scrbook (working with standalone documentclass)

Tags: pgfplots, labels, tikz-3dplot, scrbook, raise

To add some spacing between touching tick labels, I raise the according box with `raisebox{}`. Working with 2D graphs until now, this commonly did the trick for me.

However, I am unable to raise a `zticklabel` in my 3D graph. Strangely enough, I was able to raise the `zticklabel` when using `\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}`, but not with `\documentclass[]{scrbook}`:

```
% 'raisebox{}' in 'zticklabel' works with documentclass 'standalone'
% \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

% 'raisebox{}' in 'zticklabel' does not work with documentclass 'scrbook'
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\shiftleft}[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{
      width = 0.65\linewidth,
      height = 0.65\linewidth,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 1,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 1,
    zmin = 0.90,
    zmax = 1.10,
    %
    xticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    },
    xticklabel={
        \ifnum \ticknum=1
        \shiftleft{2.5ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
        \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi
    },
    %
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    },
    %
    zticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2,
    },
    zticklabel={
        \ifnum \ticknum=1
        \raisebox{2.5ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
        \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi
    },
    grid=major,
    minor tick num=1,
    minor z tick num=4,
    view={210}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3+[mesh, scatter, samples=10, domain=0:1]
        {(x * 6 + 110) / (y * 8 + 110)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Nonetheless, shifting the `xticklabel` with `shiftleft{}` works with both document classes. Furthermore, I am able to raise a `yticklabel` of 2D graphs inside `scrbook` documents like so:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            width = 0.65\linewidth,
            height = 0.65\linewidth,
            enlargelimits = false,
        }

        \begin{axis}[
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            },
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            },
            yticklabel={
                \ifnum \ticknum=1
                \raisebox{1ex}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
                \else\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\fi
            }
        ]
            \addplot+[domain=0:1] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why am I unable to raise the `zticklabel` of 3D graphs inside `scrbook` documents? Is there any fix or workaround for this?